# EJS cannot read variable in html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, ejs

I'm new at backend programming and having diffuculty with using EJS and routes. I'm using a database as well. The problem is , a dynamic js variable cannot displaying in ejs view file. I mean "message" like "the password does not match

## <%= message %>

Can you help me ? These are my codes. I've shortened them as much as i can do. I don't think database files are important for the solution so did not include them. Thanks !

This is my main index.js file :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');   

const dotenv = require('dotenv') ; 
dotenv.config({path:'./.env'})
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //false yerine true da koyulabilir.
app.use(express.json()); 
//Define routes
app.use('/',require('./routes/pages'));
app.use('/auth',require('./routes/auth'));

app.listen(3000, () => {

    console.log("Listening on port 3000");

});
```

This is my auth.js(controllers) file :

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const db_kullanici_auth = require("../data/kullanici_auth_db"); //it's a database importing

exports.register = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    //         console.log(req.body) ;
    // res.send("Form submitted") ;
        // let query = "SELECT email FROM register;"
        // const allDB = await (db_kullanici_auth.execute(query));
        // const projeler_db = allDB[0];
        // console.log(projeler_db);

        const { company_name_reg, name_reg, surname_reg, department_name_reg, position_name_reg, password_reg, password_confirm_reg, adres_reg, adres2_reg, zip_reg, sehir_reg, ulke_reg, telefon_kodu_reg, telefon_numarasi_reg, email_reg } = req.body;

        await (db_kullanici_auth.execute('SELECT email FROM register WHERE email = ? ', [email_reg], (error, results) => {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

            if (results.length > 0) {

                console.log(results);

                return res.render('kayit_ol', {

                    message: 'Email is already in use'

                });

            }
            else if (password_reg !== password_confirm_reg) {

                console.log(results);
                return res.render('kayit_ol', {
                    message: 'Passwords does not match'

                });

            }
            // let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password_reg,8) ;
            // console.log(hashedPassword) ;
        }));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

This is my auth.js(routes) file :

```
const express = require('express') ; 
const router = express.Router() ;
const authController = require('../controllers/auth');

router.post("/kayit_ol",authController.register);


module.exports = router ;
```

Comment: Please put stack trace to here.